# How to debug an iOS app with lldb on the command line on a device without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, terminal, lldb

Is is possible to launch and debug one of my iOS apps in development on an iPhone (or other iOS device) without using Xcode?

I would like to do this from the command line using lldb.

I figure that since it can be done with Xcode that it may be possible to debug strictly from within the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

[ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) can do that.

```
brew install node
npm install -g ios-deploy

ios-deploy -d -W -b path/to/foo.app
```

It will copy the app bundle to your connected device, launch the app, and start an lldb session for the app.

I just tested it right now. OSX 10.12.6, iOS 11.0.2, Xcode 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to debug your app without using xcode on a jailbroken device all you need is to add entitlements  on debug server if you wish to debug apps you did not build , there is a great explanation here http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver , once you attached to the process on the device just launch lldb on your computer and debug